# Editing 'Now Playing' embed in Discord Music Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to edit this embed to where the slider "" moves every 7 seconds. I also want the "Time Remaining:" to change every 7 seconds.

For now all that changes is the "queue.formattedCurrentTime" and "song.formattedDuration"

Here's the code I have so far. Got any tips?

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js-light')
const createBar = require('string-progressbar')
const { toColonNotation } = require('colon-notation')
module.exports = {
    name: 'np',
    aliases: ['nowplaying', 'currentsong'],
    description: 'Show the currently playing song.',
    usage: `${prefix}np`,
    run: async(bot, message) => {
        const queue = bot.distube.getQueue(message)
        if(!queue) return message.channel.send('There are no songs in the queue.')
        if(!queue && !bot.distube.isPlaying(message)) return('There is nothing playing.')
        const song = queue.songs[0]
        const name = song.name
        const user = song.user.tag
        const avatar = song.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, format: "png" })
        const link = song.url
        const time = song.duration * 1000
        const currenttime = queue.currentTime
        const tn = song.thumbnail
        const remaining = (time - currenttime < 0 ? "◉ LIVE" : time - currenttime)
        try {
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(name)
            .setAuthor(user, avatar)
            .setURL(link)
            .setDescription(`${createBar(time === 0 ? currenttime: time, currenttime, 27, "─", "")[0]} \`[${queue.formattedCurrentTime}/${song.formattedDuration}]\`\n` +
            `${bot.distube.isPaused(message) === true ? "⏸" : "▶"} ${time === 0 ? "" : `| **Time Remaining:**\`${toColonNotation(remaining)}\``}`)
            .addField('In Channel:',  `**${message.member.voice.channel.name}**`, { inline: true })
            .addField('From Playlist:', song.fromPlaylist ? "✅" : "❌", { inline: true })
            .setColor('#c1abff')
            .setThumbnail(`${tn}`)
            message.channel.send(embed).then((message) => {
                var countdown = 10;
                const interval = setInterval(() => {
                    if (countdown < 0) clearInterval(interval);
                    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(name)
                    .setAuthor(user, avatar)
                    .setURL(link)
                    .setDescription(`${createBar(time === 0 ? currenttime: time, currenttime, 27, "─", "")[0]} \`[${queue.formattedCurrentTime}/${song.formattedDuration}]\`\n` +
                    `${bot.distube.isPaused(message) === true ? "⏸" : "▶"} ${time === 1 ? "" : `| **Time Remaining:**\`` + new Date()`${toColonNotation(remaining)}\``}`)
                    .addField('In Channel:',  `**${message.member.voice.channel.name}**`, { inline: true })
                    .addField('From Playlist:', song.fromPlaylist ? "✅" : "❌", { inline: true })
                    .setColor('#c1abff')
                    .setThumbnail(`${tn}`)
                    message.edit(embed)
                }, 7000)
            })
        } catch (e) {
            message.channel.send(`There was an issue: \n\`${e}\``)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating the embed constantly is probably not the ideal way of going about this.

Instead, you can try what I have in my 'Now Playing' command and use "Stylish-text" in your embed.

```
const bar = require(`stylish-text`)

    function toReadableTime(given){
        var time = given;
        var minutes = "0" + Math.floor(time / 60);
        var seconds = "0" + (time - minutes * 60);
        return minutes.substr(-2) + ":" + seconds.substr(-2);
    }

    const current = Math.floor(serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.streamTime / 1000) //ms --> seconds
    const end = serverQueue.songs[0].length //video in seconds
    
    const value = (current * (100 / end) / 5)
    
    bar.default.full = "█";
    bar.default.empty = " - ";
    bar.default.start = "";
    bar.default.end = "";
    bar.default.text = "{bar}";

`${toReadableTime(current)} - [${bar.progress(20, value)}] - ${toReadableTime(end)}` //This would go in your embed
```

Output:

[image: Example usage]

Answer (score 0):

I have used your code and tried to fix it, and now I have the solution, instead of using

```
const time = song.duration * 1000
const currenttime = queue.currentTime
```

use

```
${progressbar.splitBar(queue.duration, queue.currentTime + 5, size = 27, line = '-', slider = '')[0]}
```

instead.

Please note that `${queue.paused ? '▶' : '⏸'}` is only working in the latest disturbed version.